# Moment of Inertia of a Disk with a small hole in it

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

[image]

We have a disk of radius **b**. Suppose we cut a small portion ( a circle of radius **a**) from the disk. Now the mass of this object (with this hole) is **M**. What is the *moment of inertia* of this object about the axis shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The moment of inertia of the object in the drawing is equal to the moment of inertia of a disk of radius "b" minus the moment of inertia of a disk of radius "a".

Comment: Yes, but you have to be able to determine the MOI of each shape.